# Algorithm for Win32 ListView typeahead search

Tags: listview, winapi

When you type into a ListBox or ListView in Win32, it will search for a string starting with what you typed, and select that item. Does anybody know the exact algorithm? I would like to replicate it in a WinUI ListView.

Things I've noticed:

- If you press a letter, it will search downwards for the first element starting with that letter.
- If you press the letter multiple times, it will select the next elements starting with that letter
- But it also searches for prefixes. If you type multiple different letters, it will select the next element starting with that string. But if you wait too long between letters, it will start a new string.
- Repeated letters take precidence before prefixes. So if you have `aa`, `ea`, `eb`, `ee`,   and press `ee`, it will select `ea` and then `eb`.
- It seems to be case-insensitive. I don't know how it handles input methods.

Comment: It sounds like you're pretty much described the algorithm. If you implement that it'd be pretty close.

Comment: Yeah, I think I figured out the edge cases and it works nicely. If I find some time I'll answer my own question I guess.